# Browsing Loops in VI Editor

Tags: unix

In vi editor, how can I move the cursor from the beginning of a block (if,while,for) to the end of the block (fi,done..)

Answer (score 0):

If the language uses braces (C, C++, Java, ...), then you can use '%' to bounce back and forth between matching braces `{}`, and brackets `[]`, and parentheses `()`.  You can also move to the start of the next or previous function (or other construct starting with an open brace in column 1) using `]]` or `[[` respectively.

I don't think there's an easy way to go to the matching `fi` or `done` as in shell code.

Comment: @Inquisitive: yes.  Beware that Bourne shell `case` statements mess up parentheses because each alternative has a close parenthesis but no open parenthesis: `case $what in a) ...;; b) ...;; esac`.  Modern shells (Korn, Bash) allow, but do not require, an open parenthesis too: `case $what in (a) ...;; (b) ...;; esac`, which is a good idea because it allows bouncing on parentheses to work again.